# Sending emails from vendor's multiple domains

Tags: email

We have custom cms that currently sits on a vendor's subdomain, such as cms.vendor.com. It sends email out as coming from user@vendor.com and it seems to be working fine (using Email Queuing + SwiftMailer)

Our vendor asked us to put in the functionality for his users to be able to select from a dropdown, 3-4 other emails address associated with them from other domains he owns. Basically we need to be able to send out emails from our server labeled as being sent from @hisdomains.com, multiple domains.

I am a web programmer and have no clue when it comes to relaying messages. How would I go about being able to send out emails from his other domains? Does he need to setup permissions on his mail servers, or do I need to get into his SMTP servers to send out?

What are some things I should look out for when it comes to SPAM and gmail trusting us?

EDIT:

Not sure if my original question was clear enough. Vendor owns three domains: mysite.com, myothersite.com, mythirdsite.com. He wants a user from our crm to be able to send emails he has on those domains. So my dedicated server will be trying to send an email out as user@mysite.com, user@myothersite.com, and user@mythirdsite.com in the FROM: header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your server is allowed to send on behalf of a domain your vendor owns, you should not have a problem; just change the `From:` header to something else when you send out the e-mail.

Stuff like SPF, Sender ID and DKIM have to be properly configured to allow your server to send on behalf of any domain.

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_authentication

Comment: Thanks Jack. What would be required on the vendor's side to implement the proper config? A system administrator editing sendmail files?

Comment: Sendmail is used on the receiving end of email delivery; my answer focuses on the sending part, i.e. configuring email authentication, which can be done mostly using DNS changes (SPF, DomainKeys) to assert that your email server is allowed to send emails on behalf of that domain.

Answer (score 1):

Any domain where the mx record resolves to the same server will work. so user@any.domain will email the same user on the mx contingent server.

To answer your question - just make sure that the mx records in the DNS zone file for each domain name points to the same server as the domain you want to share emails on.

also dependent on server configuration (like shared or whatever) I'm assuming it's dedicated with a simple email server installed. I'm not sure on cPanel/shared servers. but possibly the same.

Comment: Not sure I understand your answer. So if vendor has email@x.com, email@y.com, and email@z.com, and I want to send an email out from my servers spoofing those three domains, which DNS records would I need to edit?

Comment: If those domains are in your hosts file - (you'll have to look that up) and the DNS zone MX records point to the server IP address that will be sending the emails then you can send emails as that address. But unless the reverse MX lookup done by email clients such as Yahoo,gMail,Outlook,etc... resolves to the server it was sent from it will most likely go into spam folder.

Comment: So if I get the vendor to put our server's ip address in the hosts file,  you are saying they will still probably get marked as spam?

Comment: No, hold on a sec I'm gonna try to re-explain.

Comment: I don't believe you are going to be able to do this easily. In order to be sure you won't end up in the spam folder you would have to have your clients alter their DNS zone file to match their MX record with your servers IP address. Then if you wanted them to reply to the same address it's being sent from you'd have to put the domain in YOUR hosts file on YOUR server. and the email would arrive in an existing users mailbox only - so you have to be sure that each user had an actual user on the server in order to receive mail.

Comment: otherwise just use the mail function and change the headers to be whatever you want, but most clients will spam it immediately as the reverse DNS mx lookup does not match the sending server IP

Comment: It's like this to prevent exactly what your doing. Otherwise people could seamlessly send emails from "@yourbank" requesting you to sign in for example.